# mySQL - How can I make multi update in one query?

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 update queries, same tables but different rows and values.
Since its same table, making 2 queries is an unprofessional way.

```
UPDATE members SET age="18" WHERE nick = "John"
UPDATE members SET height="180" WHERE nick = "Stuart"
```

Is there a better (1 query) method for this ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just use the right `where` clause:

```
UPDATE members
    SET age = 18
WHERE nick IN ('John', 'Stuart')
```

I am guessing that `age` is an integer.  I should also point out that storing "age" in a database is very uncommon -- because it is a bad idea.  Every day, people's ages change.

EDIT:

```
UPDATE members
    SET age = (CASE WHEN nick = 'John' THEN 18 ELSE age END),
        height = (CASE WHEN nick = 'Stuart' THEN 180 ELSE height END)
WHERE nick IN ('John', 'Stuart')
```

I really read the problem as updating only age.  For this, you can use a case statement:

Comment: I thought of this at first, but it seems he wants to change the age for john and height for stuart

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but that only updates age ? Also no its not age, I just simplified for the question, actually they're normal text values.

Comment: @user3304007 . . . You are right.  I really read the original question and thought both queries were updating age, but that seems to have been a misreading on my part.

Comment: Gotcha. Can I ask you which one should I use for better performance ? Lets say the database is huge (too many users), 2 update queries, or 1 query with case statement ?

Comment: The performance should be similar, if you do the two updates in a single transaction.  If they are in multiple transactions, then the single `update` should be faster.